# if has no child how to not toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Hi I develop checkbox and I have some issue.if my li parents has no ul child it musn't be toggle. I'm talking about red arrows which is the left of li element.

I got solved problem thanks to @Arun P Johny just one more thing left I have to do is when clicked label checkbox musn't be checked only thoose which has got ul child

[see my codeson codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/zqoNQg)

html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>No Title</title>
</head>
<body> 

    <div class="new-checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li class="hasUl">
        <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
        <label for="input1">kategori <strong>(1)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
            <label for="input11">kategori<strong>(11)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
            <label for="input12">kategori <strong>(12)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
            <label for="input13">kategori <strong>(13)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
        <label for="input2">kategori <strong>(2)</strong>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="hasUl">
        <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
        <label for="input3">kategori <strong>(3)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
            <label for="input31">kategori <strong>(31)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
            <label for="input32">kategori <strong>(32)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
            <label for="input33">kategori <strong>(33)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
                <label for="input331">kategori <strong>(331)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
                <label for="input332">kategori <strong>(332)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
                <label for="input333">kategori <strong>(333)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- new checkbox-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}

.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content: "\25b6";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li.downCheck:before
{
    content: "\25bc" !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*
.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content:"";
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-16.png") no-repeat left center;
      margin-top: 2px;
}
 li.downCheck:before{
   content:"";
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-16.png") no-repeat left center !important;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
*/
.new-checkbox li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

 
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ li::before {
  content: "\25bc";
}

.new-checkbox li ul {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox li.has-checked > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

jquery codes

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked).parent().toggleClass('has-checked', checked);

    $li.parentsUntil('.new-checkbox', 'li').each(function() {
      var $checks = $(this).find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
      $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !$checks.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

      $(this).toggleClass('has-checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    });

  });


    $('.new-checkbox li.hasUl input[type="checkbox"]').on("click",function(e) {
         $(this).parent("li").stop().toggleClass("downCheck"); 

      });

    $(".new-checkbox ul li > * li:has(ul)").addClass("downCheck");


});
```

Comment: Not sure what you are after

Comment: what do you mean by don't want to toggle

Comment: I added codepen link @ArunPJohny

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have red icon left on li element if I clicked it's rotate himselfto down but if it has no child it musn't rotate ?

Comment: Your logic is in the wrong place.  Rather than no action if no child, you should not show the red icon if there's no child (or show it, but greyed-out).  Otherwise you'll just annoy your users.

Comment: @freedomn-m I just need to one thing.if I will be click label which has ul child checkbox musn't checked but if I clicked checkbox it has to be checked not label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `has-checked` class to style the element, there is no need to have a new class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.new-checkbox li:has(ul)').addClass('parent');

  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked).parent().toggleClass('has-checked', checked);

    $li.parentsUntil('.new-checkbox', 'li').each(function() {
      var $checks = $(this).find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
      $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !$checks.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

      $(this).toggleClass('has-checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}
.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content: "\25b6";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li.parent.has-checked:before {
  content: "\25bc" !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*
.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content:"";
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-16.png") no-repeat left center;
      margin-top: 2px;
}
 li.downCheck:before{
   content:"";
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-16.png") no-repeat left center !important;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
*/

.new-checkbox li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ li::before {
  content: "\25bc";
}
.new-checkbox li ul {
  display: none;
}
.new-checkbox li.has-checked > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li class="hasUl">
      <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
      <label for="input1">kategori <strong>(1)</strong>
      </label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
          <label for="input11">kategori<strong>(11)</strong>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
          <label for="input12">kategori <strong>(12)</strong>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
          <label for="input13">kategori <strong>(13)</strong>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
      <label for="input2">kategori <strong>(2)</strong>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="hasUl">
      <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
      <label for="input3">kategori <strong>(3)</strong>
      </label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
          <label for="input31">kategori <strong>(31)</strong>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
          <label for="input32">kategori <strong>(32)</strong>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
          <label for="input33">kategori <strong>(33)</strong>
          </label>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
              <label for="input331">kategori <strong>(331)</strong>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
              <label for="input332">kategori <strong>(332)</strong>
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
              <label for="input333">kategori <strong>(333)</strong>
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- new checkbox-->
```

Comment: thanks @Arun but I guess .downCheck icon is reverse that you edit.you so helped to me

Comment: I don't know how but I want to thank you @Arun धन्यवाद :)

Comment: by the way is it important if li has child wherever I click checkbox has to be checked.but if my checkbox has child if I click label it has to be open child is there any way to do ? last thing

Comment: @fortherest not sure what you meant

Comment: if I click label checkbox musn't be checked

Comment: just for which has ul child

Comment: @fortherest remove the `for` attribute of the label

Comment: hi..is there any way to do ? not working and I don't want to messed up.. I want to do that before I die what have to do now ? do I have to change my codes stratch ?

Comment: I updated.now it works as I want except that one thing. if I click just checkbox it has to be checked or filled will css as checked

Answer (score 0):

Replace Code

```
$('.new-checkbox li.hasUl input[type="checkbox"]').on("click",function(e) {
     $(this).parent("li:has(ul)").stop().toggleClass("downCheck"); 
  });
```

From

```
$('.new-checkbox li.hasUl input[type="checkbox"]').on("click",function(e) {
     $(this).parent("li").stop().toggleClass("downCheck"); 
  });
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpBqjz?editors=1010)

Comment: thanks but if I unchecked my all checkbox which is under my li they not hiding themself?

Comment: hey @Dhaval you are great so grateful. but one more thing has left.if all checkbox has unchecked .Downcheck is rotate to down I don't want to this.it must be rotate right sorry about my english